# How do you add icons to application in GTK#

Tags: c#, windows, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I have this very basic GTK# window, but it seems that there are missing icons on title bar. I believe there should be icons for closing, maximizing and minimizing window.

[image: screenshot]

My question is: how do you add icons in GTK 3.22.7? How GTK determines where icons are going to be searched for?

I suppose the answer would be similiar for GTK# and GTK. If you don't know how it's done in C#, can you please write answer for pure GTK? I might be able to figure out how to port it to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer:

You need to have icons directory structured like that:

```
icons/
├── Adwaita
│   ├── 16x16
│   ├── 22x22
│   ├── 24x24
│   ├── 256x256
│   ├── 32x32
│   ├── 48x48
│   ├── 512x512
│   ├── 64x64
│   ├── 8x8
│   ├── 96x96
│   ├── cursors
│   ├── icon-theme.cache
│   ├── index.theme
│   ├── scalable
│   └── scalable-up-to-32
└── hicolor
    ├── 128x128
    ├── 16x16
    ├── 192x192
    ├── 22x22
    ├── 24x24
    ├── 256x256
    ├── 32x32
    ├── 36x36
    ├── 48x48
    ├── 512x512
    ├── 64x64
    ├── 72x72
    ├── 96x96
    ├── icon-theme.cache
    ├── index.theme
    ├── scalable
    └── symbolic
```

Then, you have to specify path to icons/

```
Gtk.IconTheme.Default.AppendSearchPath(@"D:\dev\git\GtkApp1\bin\Debug\icons");
```

You can also choose desired icon theme to use

```
Gtk.Settings.Default.IconThemeName = "Adwaita";
```

[image: it works]

Comment: If the icons are in the correct `share/` subdir it should be picked up without appending the path yourself also.

Comment: Unfortunately, they weren't picked from `share/icons/` relative to application .exe.

Comment: The `share` dir must be in the same directory as the `bin` dir.

Comment: Yup, now it works when I placed it next to `bin`. Is it documented somewhere what is GTK lookup order?

Comment: On Windows the directory lookups use this: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Windows-Compatibility-Functions.html#g-win32-get-package-installation-directory-of-module